# Apple iPhone5c website like color combination selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am browsing at the web to find a jQuery plugin that can give me a product color selector similar in the web page of [iPhone 5c](https://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/). I think this is the closest jQuery plugin I found the [Product Colorizer](http://sandbox.nikorablin.com/productColorizer/). But this is not what I am looking for, coz I alrady have the images of the different color combinations of the product and I want it to work similar to the webpage of iPhone5c. I hope you guys can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the images of the Apple page and created the CSS by myself. The CSS needs to be improved, but I just made a quick example.

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="green"></a></li>
     <li><a class="blue"></a></li>
     <li><a class="yellow"></a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
}

ul li{
    display: inline-block; 
}

ul li a {
    z-index: 1;
    background: no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.green{
    background-image: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-5c/a/images/colornav_green.png);
}

a.green:hover {
    background: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-5c/a/images/colornav_green.png) 0px 40px;
}

.blue{
    background-image: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-5c/a/images/colornav_blue.png);
}

a.blue:hover {
    background: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-5c/a/images/colornav_blue.png) 0px 80px;
}

.yellow{
    background-image: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-5c/a/images/colornav_yellow.png);
}

a.yellow:hover {
    background: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-5c/a/images/colornav_yellow.png) 0px 80px;
}
```

The first mouse over is set as an 'active' link.

http://jsfiddle.net/06p951dv/

---

### If you want the 'selected' image on click, you can use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var oldButton = null;
    $('ul li a').on('click', function(){
        if (oldButton){
            $(oldButton).removeClass('selected');
        }
        oldButton = this;
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/06p951dv/2/

---

### Example with the iPhone images

You have to add following CSS:

```
#green, #blue, #yellow{
    display: none;
}
```

.. and following JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var oldButton = null;
    $('ul li a').on('click', function(){
        if (oldButton){
            $(oldButton).removeClass('selected');
            if ($(this).attr('class') !== $(oldButton).attr('class')){ // added
                $('#' + $(oldButton).attr('class')).toggle('slow');
            } // end added
        }
        if ($(this).attr('class') !== $(oldButton).attr('class')){ // added
            $('#' + $(this).attr('class')).toggle('slow');
        } // end added
        oldButton = this;
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

And some extra HTML:

```
<img id="green" src="https://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/home/images/color_green_none.jpg#gallery-cases-green-none" />
<img id="blue" src="https://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/home/images/color_blue_none.jpg#gallery-cases-blue-none" />
<img id="yellow" src="https://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/home/images/color_yellow_none.jpg#gallery-cases-yellow-none" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/06p951dv/3/

---

### UPDATE

I've noticed that Apple uses a common image name pattern too improve coding. They use `https://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/home/images/color_"+phoneColor+"_"+phoneCase+".jpg#gallery-cases-"+phoneColor+"-"+phoneCase` as image url. Now it is very easy to set the right image:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="phone">
    <li><a class="green"></a></li>
     <li><a class="blue"></a></li>
     <li><a class="yellow"></a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="case">
    <li><a class="green"></a></li>
     <li><a class="blue"></a></li>
     <li><a class="yellow"></a></li>
</ul>

<img id="img" src="" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var oldButton = null;
    var oldCase = null;
    var phoneColor = "green";
    var phoneCase = "none";
    $('#phone li a').on('click', function(){
        if (oldButton){
            $(oldButton).removeClass('selected');
        }
        phoneColor = $(this).attr('class').replace(" selected", "");
        setSrc();
        oldButton = this;
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    $('#case li a').on('click', function(){
        if (oldCase){
            $(oldCase).removeClass('selected');
        }
        phoneCase = $(this).attr('class').replace(" selected", "");
        setSrc();
        oldCase = this;
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    var setSrc = function(){
         $('#img').attr("src", "https://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/home/images/color_"+phoneColor+"_"+phoneCase+".jpg#gallery-cases-"+phoneColor+"-"+phoneCase);
    };
});
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/06p951dv/5/

Comment: Thanks @guyT I appreciate that, it really helps, but my problem now is the color combinations. In the iPhone5c website there are two options, for color of phone and color of case, and you can choose a different color combinations using the two selectors. I'm sorry if I sound dumb, but is there a way to add those features in your code sir?

Comment: @markyeoj Check out my updated answer. **hint** use '@' and a name otherwise I receive no notification.